# How I can minimize this jQuery calender size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

[image]

I am using calendar (date time 24 hours format) from [calendar](http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/datetimepicker-demo9.htm). I am facing problem from size of this. On this site, it was small. But just copied code from their downloads to my page. It was opening in a large scale.

I can display it as it is on that site. I am using Demo3.

Answer (score 1):

It is the problem with font

try this

```
 #ui-datepicker-div { font-size: 10px; }
```

or

```
.ui-widget {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```